# Push Notification in App Store Review

Tags: swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I have made an app, and consider sending it for review, I have used the tutorial from Parse.com for setting up push notifications for my App, and before saving i changed the provisining profile to one for app store (where push notifications were enabled).

Does this mean the app is using APN API, which is required for posting to the app store (guidelines 5.1). Do I need to enable push notifications in capabilities or anything else to make my app pass point 5.1 in the app store review guidelines?

5.1 "Apps that provide Push Notifications without using the Apple Push Notification (APN) API will be rejected"

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#push-notifications

Comment: Have you test the push notifications with your app?

Comment: yes, its working fine, so i was just wondering if there was some kind of formal requirement for marking push notifications in capabilities or anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit your app to review! :)

Parse is using APNS to send pushes so you are fine. You don't need to edit anything to pass 5.1 point of apple guidelines.